# Connecting Android device to a basic TV

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

How can I connect my Android KitKat to a basic TV (not smart TV) with the cable of CD player or other? Any trick or tips?

Comment: Do you mean connect it to the tv, to play video? Or just connect the audio part?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what do you want to achieve? With "the cable of CD player", you're giving a hint of using TV for audio output, but is that what you really want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Android device you are using, this will connect to an old TV:

[RCA Compact RF Modulator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0014KKV7W)

What are you using for the video out on the Android device?